# What's the syntax to pass a dictionary as an input type in Flyte?

Tags: flyte

I'm trying to pass a dictionary as a parameter to a batch_sub_task, but I'm not quite sure how to define the @input.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `Types.Generic` as the type? It maps to a json object in Python.

```
Use this to specify a simple JSON type.

When used with an SDK-decorated method, expect this behavior from the default type engine:

    As input:
        1) If set, a Python dict with JSON-ifiable primitives and nested lists or maps.
        2) Otherwise, a None value will be received.

    As output:
        1) User code may pass a Python dict with arbitrarily nested lists and dictionaries.  JSON-ifiable
           primitives may also be specified.
        2) Output can also be nulled with a None value.

    From command-line:
        Specify a JSON string.

.. code-block:: python

    @inputs(a=Types.Generic)
    @outputs(b=Types.Generic)
    @python_task
    def operate(wf_params, a, b):
        if a['operation'] == 'add':
            a['value'] += a['operand']  # a['value'] is a number
        elif a['operation'] == 'merge':
            a['value'].update(a['some']['nested'][0]['field'])
        b.set(a)
```